# Trouble with Using Unit Test in Python

Tags: python, testing, automation

I'm making an auto grader for professors to upload a folder of code submissions and a test folder, and my program should run the tests and return a grade. I'm having trouble using the test suite in python, as I keep getting 1 test ran. Here's my code, I believe it is in the run_test method.

```
class gradeCode:
    
    def __init__(self, submissions_path, unit_test_path, constraints_path):
        self.submissions_path = submissions_path
        self.unit_test_path = unit_test_path
        self.constraints_path = constraints_path
        
    def print_report(self, report):
        for student_report in report:
            student_id = student_report['file']
            total_tests = student_report['total_tests']
            successful_tests = student_report['successful_tests']
            grade = student_report['grade']
            
            report = ''
            report += f'\n Student ID: {student_id}'
            report += f'\n {successful_tests} of {total_tests} tests passed.'
            report += f'\n Grade: {grade:.2f}%'
            report += f'\n---------------------------------------------------'
            
            print(report)
        
    class AutoGraderTest(unittest.TestCase):
        def __init__(self, submission_code, unit_test_code):
            super().__init__()
            self.submission_code = submission_code
            self.unit_test_code = unit_test_code
        def runTest(self):
            pass
        def test_submission(self):
            exec(self.unit_test_code, globals())
            exec(self.submission_code, globals())
                
    def run_test(self):
        report = []
        unit_test_path = 'unit_test_temp.py'
        with open(self.unit_test_path, 'r') as unit_test_file:
            unit_test_code = unit_test_file.read()
        
        for submission in os.listdir(self.submissions_path):
            if (submission.endswith('.py')):
                submission_path = os.path.join(self.submissions_path, submission)
                
                with open(submission_path, 'r') as submission_file: 
                    submission_code = submission_file.read()
                    
                suite = unittest.TestSuite()
                auto_grader_test = self.AutoGraderTest(submission_code, unit_test_code)

                # Clear the test suite and add the test cases for this submission
                
                suite.addTest(auto_grader_test)

                # Run the test case and collect the results
                test_runner = unittest.TextTestRunner()
                test_results = test_runner.run(suite)
                
                total_tests = test_results.testsRun
                successful_tests = total_tests - len(test_results.failures) - len(test_results.errors)
                grade = (successful_tests / total_tests) * 100
                
                submission_results = {
                    'file': submission.strip('.py'),
                    'grade': grade,
                    'total_tests': total_tests,
                    'successful_tests': successful_tests
                }
                
                report.append(submission_results)
        self.print_report(report)
        return report
```

Test File:

```
import unittest
import glob
from calculator import Calculator

class UnitTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.calculator = Calculator()

    def test_add(self):
        result = self.calculator.add(2, 3)
        self.assertEqual(result, 5)

    def test_subtract(self):
        result = self.calculator.subtract(5, 3)
        self.assertEqual(result, 2)

    def test_multiply(self):
        result = self.calculator.multiply(2, 3)
        self.assertEqual(result, 6)
        
    def test_divide(self):
        result = self.calculator.divide(3, 6)
        result2 = self.calculator.divide(1, 4)
        self.assertEqual(result, 2)
        self.assertEqual(result2, 0.25)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Any help is appreciated.